# using xcode python3 with pyenv on mac?

Tags: xcode, pyenv

sorry but I am a bit anal about my mac mini m1 and keeping it in order.

I have ventura and installed xcode so I have python 3.9.6.

I would like to use pyenv for projects, however pyenv does not seem to know that python3 is installed...

% pyenv versions

- system (set by /Users/billd/.pyenv/version)

can I use pyenv with the xcode python 3.9.6 - I have googled this and I am not finding any answers that don't seem to involve installing pythong again with pyenv or homebrew.